# Saving image from surface view to DCIM directory

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

So I have a frame view I stream the camera view using `SurfaceView`. 
I want to save the taken image to a new folder `DCIM/ZES` which does not exists yet. In the code below Im getting the right path and after the first atempt `mkdirs()` return true. the thing is the directory DOES NOT get created no matter what even though `exists()` method will return `true`

after the first attempt on the same dir.

getting the output file name the creating the directory:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // getting the 'MES' folder route
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MES");
    Log.i("CAMERA", "SAVING IMAGE TO FILE");
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

saving the image:

```
Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d("CAMERA", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }


        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
            Log.i("FILE", "File was saved in " + pictureFile.getName());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("CAMERA", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("CAMERA", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

I then use the `pictureCallback` in `takePicture()` method and that works fine

What is not working is: no picture is saved. no directory is created (that I can see). checking if the directory exists using `exists()` return `true` after first try.

Looked for the whole day for a solution online but no success,
Tried to use `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` method but cant configure the directory images are saved so its no good.

Really frustrated with this one

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this problem occur in only your device or in other devices too? And can you save them in internal storage?

Comment: having the exact same results on android studio emulator, ONE plus x, and Mobix devices. added all the permissions needed in `manifests` file and on approved storage, camera and microphone usage on all devices and emulator for my app